Efficiently Handling Polymorphic Relationships and Statuses in a Large-Scale Relational Database with Laravel
I'm currently working on a project using Laravel where I need to handle statuses across multiple types of entities (e.g., posts, comments, etc.). I've set up a polymorphic relationship to link statuses to different entities. Here's a brief overview of my setup:
Statuses Table:
Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('entity');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Entity Statuses Table (Polymorphic Relationship):
  Schema::create('entity_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('status_id')->constrained('statuses');
    $table->morphs('entity');
    $table->timestamps();
});
$table->index(['entity_type', 'entity_id']);

My goal is to store all statuses of the models in a single table that relates them to the corresponding records, using only one table to keep the database size manageable, while also optimizing it as much as possible.
Question: How can I optimize this setup to handle large volumes of data efficiently? Are there best practices or alternative approaches for managing polymorphic relationships and statuses in a relational database? Any advice on improving indexing, caching strategies, or other optimization techniques would be greatly appreciated.
Additionally, I would like recommendations on the best database to use for this setup.
Thank you in advance!

Efficiency and polymorph dont play together. If you statuses are not dynamic, use an enum or int field. If they are dynamic, break it into two different tables for efficiency. Polymorph doesnt optimize databases. If you have 20 comments and 10 posts you will have 30 entries either in two seperated table or in the same table using polymorph. having them in the same table is slower to query especially since one of the condition is a string comparaison.

In response to your comment, would it be better to create a separate status table for each entity and then relate them to the entities using a pivot table with a natural SQL relationship?

IF you have dynamic statuses. otherwise, use a simple field with either of type enum or int (unsigned tiny int with constants in you models). InnoDB database engine performs best with ints

What is the problem that you are trying to address by using polymorphic relationships? Polymorphism adds complexity, reduces performance, and hinders using the database's built-in referential integrity facilities. I don't see anything about handling status that would benefit from using polymorphism.
